# What's $\alpha+\beta$ if we have: $\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+13\alpha=1$ and $\beta^3-6\beta^2+13\beta=19$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Real)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's $\alpha+\beta$ if we have $\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+13\alpha=1$ and $\beta^3-6\beta^2+13\beta=19$? Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real.

Firstly, I subtracted the two equations and got the following:
$$\alpha^3-\beta^3-6(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+13(\alpha-\beta)=-18$$ Then I tried to factorize the left hand side as: $$(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2-6\alpha-6\beta+13)=-18$$ 
At this point it seems we can't go on!
Then I tried adding the two equations as: $$(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^2-\alpha\beta+\beta^2-6\alpha-6\beta+13)+12\alpha\beta=20$$
unfortunately, again I can't continue!
Is there any special creativity needed for solving this question?

Comment: By numerical computation, the answer seems to be 4.

Comment: Thank you , but  this is  a pure algebraic question

Comment: If you're really desperate to solve this, you can always simply find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using the cubic formula.

Comment: Have you tried simply solving each equation seperately, thus obtaining $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Yes,but again it seems difficult!

Comment: See [this page](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/).

Comment: There are three $\alpha$ s and three $\beta$ s and we have nine possibilities.

Comment: Please remember that the title of a post is not part of the post itself, and in particular the body of the post should be readable on its own, without reading the title first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get rid of the quadratic terms we write $\alpha:=a+2$, $\beta:=b+2$. Then
$$1=\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+13\alpha=(a+2)^3-6(a+2)^2+13(a+2)=a^3+a+10\ ,$$
and similarly
$$19=\beta^3-6\beta^2+13\beta=b^3+b+10\ .$$
It follows that $a$ and $b$ satisfy the equations
$$a^3+a=-9,\quad b^3+b=9\ .$$
Now (an unexpected) symmetry comes to our rescue: 
As $t\mapsto t^3+t$ is  monotonically increasing there is exactly one $b=:b_*>0$ satisfying the second of these equations, and it is then obvious that $a:=-b_*$ is the unique solution of the first of these equations. It follows that necessarily
$$\alpha+\beta=-b_*+2 +b_*+2=4\ .$$

Comment: How could you guess  that substitution?

Comment: A revision of last part of Christian's method: add the two equations as: $$a^3+b^3+a+b=0$$  , then factorize left hand as:  $$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2+1)=0$$ , so $a+b=0$ , then: $\alpha+\beta=4$

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi, I think the idea is to use : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic

Answer (score 13):

Let $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+13x,$ Then $f'(x)=3x^2-12x+13 = 3[(x-2)^2]+1>0$

So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing function.

Now above we have given $f(\alpha)=1$ and $f(\beta) = 19\;,$ Where $\alpha<\beta$

Then $f(\alpha)<f(\beta)$, because the function is increasing.

Now \begin{align*}f(4-x)&=(4-x)^3-6(4-x)^2+13(4-x)\\&=64-x^3-48x+12x^2-96-6x^2+48x+52-13x\\&=-x^3+6x^2-13x+20=-f(x)+20\end{align*}
So if $x=\alpha$, Then $f(4-\alpha)=-f(\alpha)+20=19=f(\beta)$

The function is continuous and monotonically increasing, thus $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$, hence $$4-\alpha=\beta\Rightarrow \boxed{\alpha+\beta=4}$$

Comment: Is there any simpler technique for this question?? Because the audience  might not know derivative!!

Comment: To  Hamid Reza Ebrahimi , Iam also trying for that, Thanks

Comment: Why did you choose to consider f(x-4) ?

Comment: @user230452, $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+13x=x\left[(x-3)^2+4\right]$, thus $f(q-x)=\dots=-x^3+(3q-6)x^2-(3q^2-12q+13)x+f(q)$. Let's assume we want to get $f(q-x)=f(q)-f(x)$, thus we need $-x^3+(3q-6)x^2-(3q^2-12q+13)x=-x^3+6x^2-13x$. If we equating coefficients we get $q=4$, thus $f(4-x)=20-f(x) \Rightarrow f(4-\alpha)=20-f(\alpha)=f(\beta)\Rightarrow 4-\alpha=\beta$.